# Aptana with mysql for RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, aptana3, ubuntu-12.04

I have mysql installed in my Ubuntu system, And I have Aptana for RoR, how to integrate mysql with aptana fro my RoR application. Is their any plugin or something which I have to do, or what can I do..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your mysql credentials in your `config/database.yml`. Rails looks at that file when you start it up and connects to it according to your environment.

For an example on how database.yml usually looks like see [this](http://code.google.com/p/bibapp/source/browse/trunk/config/database.yml.example?r=1007). Also note, on rails 3 and above the mysql adapter is actually mysql2 (on most cases).

Comment: So, I don't have to define using app creation using Aptana's wizard

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Aptana wizard. Yes, I would suggest editing the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install mysql or mysql2 gem using following commands:
`gem install mysql2`
Add following code in Gemfile:
`gem 'mysql2'`
Then install bundle,  And set config/database.yml file as follows:
`development:
  adapter: mysql2

  database: sblog_development

  username: root

  password: root_password

  host: 127.0.0.1`

 Same setting for test and production.
Create databse using following commands:
`rake db:create` and migrate database using following commands
`rake db:migrate`
 It may work..

Comment: Check is your mysql2 gem working or not? To use mysql with ror, you have to install mysql or mysql2 gem.

Comment: I said about mysql2 gem not mysql.

Comment: Let me try to get gem install

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the app using this command.

rails new app_name -d mysql

Now You will have to give database credentials in database.yml file.